# MS SQL Server Temporal History Retention Cleanup Interval

Tags: sql-server

**The situation:**

I have been trying to get a temporal table to auto-cleanup on a 1 day history retention period (for testing purposes). I believe I have met all of Microsoft's criteria for this to work, in accordance with MS's documentation,

> Identification of matching rows and their removal from the history table occur transparently, in the background task that is scheduled and run by the system.

As you can see, under `Query 2: Results` and `Query 3: Results`, the history table is retaining data well past the 1 day mark. The temporal query is appropriately hiding the records which are outside the retention window, so I am making the assumption that SQL Server is recognizing the history retention period.

**The questions:**

1. Have I missed a critical component, causing the history table to not be cleared?

   *A. The temporal table is cleaning out.*
2. Is this mysterious "background task" not a daily occurrence / does anyone know the frequency of this task? I have yet to find this piece of information via Bing, Google, and StackOverflow searches.

   *A. Does not appear to be a daily event. I have setup a test environment to deduce the schedule (see below for updates).*

```
╒═════════╗     
│ Query 1 ║     
├─────────╜
│ --DB and Table retention configurations 
│ 
│ SELECT DB_NAME() as DatabaseName, DB.is_temporal_history_retention_enabled as TemporalHistoryRetentionEnabled 
│   , concat(SCHEMA_NAME(T1.schema_id), '.', T1.name) as TemporalTableName 
│   , concat(SCHEMA_NAME(T2.schema_id), '.', T2.name) as HistoryTableName 
│   , concat(T1.history_retention_period, ' ' , T1.history_retention_period_unit_desc) as HistoryRetentionPeriod 
│ FROM sys.tables T1 
│ OUTER APPLY (select is_temporal_history_retention_enabled from sys.databases 
│ where name = DB_NAME()) AS DB 
│ LEFT JOIN sys.tables T2 
│ ON T1.history_table_id = T2.object_id WHERE T1.temporal_type = 2 
└

╒══════════════════╗        
│ Query 1: Results ║        
├──────────────────╜
│ DatabaseName  TemporalHistoryRetentionEnabled  TemporalTableName  HistoryTableName           HistoryRetentionPeriod 
│ ------------  -------------------------------  -----------------  -------------------------  ---------------------- 
│ Sandbox       1                                dbo.TemporalTest3  dbo.TemporalTest3_History  1 DAY 
└


╒═════════╗     
│ Query 2 ║     
├─────────╜
│ --Temporal and Manual *all* records in table and history 
│ --Agent runs job every 30 minutes, writes to TemporalCleanupTest 
│ 
│ select 'Temporal' as [Action], * 
│ from TemporalTest3 
│ for system_time all 
│ union 
│ select 'Manual' as [Action], * 
│ from TemporalTest3 
│ union 
│ select 'Manual' as [Action], * 
│ from TemporalTest3_History 
│ order by Action desc, ValidTo desc 
└

╒══════════════════╗        
│ Query 2: Results ║        
├──────────────────╜
│ Action    col1    col2  ValidFrom                    ValidTo 
│ --------  ------  ----  ---------------------------  --------------------------- 
│ Temporal  ABC123  3     2019-12-04 22:50:28.4229184  9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999 
│ Manual    ABC123  3     2019-12-04 22:50:28.4229184  9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999 
│ Manual    ABC123  3     2019-12-04 22:50:22.7708507  2019-12-04 22:50:28.4229184 
│ Manual    ABC123  3     2019-12-04 22:25:39.5188391  2019-12-04 22:50:22.7708507 
│ Manual    ABC123  2     2019-12-04 22:25:35.9240760  2019-12-04 22:25:39.5188391 
│ Manual    ABC123  1     2019-12-04 22:25:31.6265788  2019-12-04 22:25:35.9240760 
│ Manual    ABC123  NULL  2019-12-04 22:25:22.4114106  2019-12-04 22:25:31.6265788 
└


╒═════════╗     
│ Query 3 ║     
├─────────╜
│ --TemporalCleanupTest: record count by TimeStamp 
│ 
│ select TimeStamp, Method, count(*)
│ from TemporalCleanupTest
│ where TimeStamp = (select max(TimeStamp) from TemporalCleanupTest)
│ group by TimeStamp, Method
│ order by TimeStamp desc, Method desc
└

╒══════════════════╗        
│ Query 3: Results ║        
├──────────────────╜
│ TimeStamp            Method    RecordCount
│ -------------------  --------  -----------
│ 2019-12-06 11:30:00  Temporal  1
│ 2019-12-06 11:30:00  Manual    6
└


╒═════════════════╗
│ Required Index: ║
├─────────────────╜
│ /*
│ Object:  Index [ix_TemporalTest3_History]
│ The cleanup task for tables with rowstore clustered index requires index to start with
│  the column corresponding the end of SYSTEM_TIME period. If such index doesn't exist, 
│  you cannot configure a finite retention period
│ */
│ CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [ix_TemporalTest3_History] ON [dbo].[TemporalTest3_History]
│ (
│   [ValidTo] ASC, --column corresponding the end of SYSTEM_TIME period
│   [ValidFrom] ASC
│ )
│ WITH
│ (
│ PAD_INDEX = OFF
│ , STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF
│ , SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF
│ , DROP_EXISTING = OFF
│ , ONLINE = OFF
│ , ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON
│ , ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
│ ) ON [PRIMARY]
└
```

**Update 2019-12-10 15:23 UTC**

> Can you share the DDL that you used to create your table (I'm interested in the temporal parameters)? – Ben Thul

```
create table [Sandbox].[dbo].[TemporalTest3]
(
    [col1] nvarchar(100)
    , constraint [PK_TemporalTest3_col1] primary key clustered ([col1] ASC)
    , [col2] nvarchar(100) NULL
    , [ValidFrom] datetime2(7) generated always as row start
    , [ValidTo] datetime2(7) generated always as row end
    , period for system_time ([ValidFrom], [ValidTo])
)
with
(
    system_versioning = on
    (
        history_table = [dbo].[TemporalTest3_History]
        , history_retention_period = 1 days
    )
)
```

**Update 2019-12-10 15:41 UTC**
The temporal table is cleaning out, however my hourly capture was kindly interrupted by the IT Staff... so I do not know when exactly the cleanout *would* have occurred. I am now left with the following questions:

1. What exactly is the background task's schedule?
2. Does it fire on service/server restart and/or missed scheduled time?

I will setup this test again, with another hourly capture, and provide an update with my findings. Surely I am not the only one with these data retention/cleanout questions.
My capture log where the cleanout was recorded:

```
┌─────────────────────┬──────────┬────────┬──────┬─────────────────────────┬─────────────────────────┐
│ TimeStamp           │ Method   │ col1   │ col2 │ ValidFrom               │ ValidTo                 │
├─────────────────────┼──────────┼────────┼──────┼─────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────┤
│ 2019-12-07 06:00:00 │ Temporal │ ABC123 │ 3    │ 2019-12-04 22:50:28.423 │ 9999-12-31 23:59:59.999 │
│ 2019-12-07 06:00:00 │ Manual   │ ABC123 │ 3    │ 2019-12-04 22:50:28.423 │ 9999-12-31 23:59:59.999 │
│ ******************* │ ******** │ ****** │ **** │ *********************** │ *********************** │
│ 2019-12-06 17:00:00 │ Temporal │ ABC123 │ 3    │ 2019-12-04 22:50:28.423 │ 9999-12-31 23:59:59.999 │
│ 2019-12-06 17:00:00 │ Manual   │ ABC123 │ 3    │ 2019-12-04 22:50:28.423 │ 9999-12-31 23:59:59.999 │
│ 2019-12-06 17:00:00 │ Manual   │ ABC123 │ 3    │ 2019-12-04 22:50:22.771 │ 2019-12-04 22:50:28.423 │
│ 2019-12-06 17:00:00 │ Manual   │ ABC123 │ 3    │ 2019-12-04 22:25:39.519 │ 2019-12-04 22:50:22.771 │
│ 2019-12-06 17:00:00 │ Manual   │ ABC123 │ 2    │ 2019-12-04 22:25:35.924 │ 2019-12-04 22:25:39.519 │
│ 2019-12-06 17:00:00 │ Manual   │ ABC123 │ 1    │ 2019-12-04 22:25:31.627 │ 2019-12-04 22:25:35.924 │
│ 2019-12-06 17:00:00 │ Manual   │ ABC123 │ NULL │ 2019-12-04 22:25:22.411 │ 2019-12-04 22:25:31.627 │
└─────────────────────┴──────────┴────────┴──────┴─────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Can you share the DDL that you used to create your table (I'm interested in the temporal parameters)?

Answer (score 4):

The background task is indeed firing off on some kind of loose "Microsoft quality schedule". Most cleanout events occurred around the start of the day (00:00) and mid-day (12:00), though some occurred at other hours. I do not know why it took time to start cleaning out the temporal history, but it is working. I have extracted the data, where changes occurred, from my hourly log into the table below. Enjoy!

If there is any further data desired, please let me know and I will supply what I can.

```
┌─────────────────────┬──────────┬──────┐
│ TimeStamp           │ Method   │ Rows │
├─────────────────────┼──────────┼──────┤
│ 2019-12-11 11:00:00 │ Temporal │ 3    │
│ 2019-12-11 11:00:00 │ Manual   │ 3    │
├─────────────────────┼──────────┼──────┤
│ 2019-12-11 12:00:00 │ Temporal │ 4 +  │
│ 2019-12-11 12:00:00 │ Manual   │ 4 +  │
├─────────────────────┼──────────┼──────┤
│ 2019-12-11 13:00:00 │ Temporal │ 3 ─  │
│ 2019-12-11 13:00:00 │ Manual   │ 4 .  │
├─────────────────────┼──────────┼──────┤
│ 2019-12-11 14:00:00 │ Temporal │ 3 .  │
│ 2019-12-11 14:00:00 │ Manual   │ 3 ─  │
├─────────────────────┼──────────┼──────┤
│ 2019-12-12 00:00:00 │ Temporal │ 3 .  │
│ 2019-12-12 00:00:00 │ Manual   │ 4 +  │
├─────────────────────┼──────────┼──────┤
│ 2019-12-12 06:00:00 │ Temporal │ 3 .  │
│ 2019-12-12 06:00:00 │ Manual   │ 3 ─  │
├─────────────────────┼──────────┼──────┤
│ 2019-12-12 12:00:00 │ Temporal │ 4 +  │
│ 2019-12-12 12:00:00 │ Manual   │ 4 +  │
├─────────────────────┼──────────┼──────┤
│ 2019-12-12 13:00:00 │ Temporal │ 3 ─  │
│ 2019-12-12 13:00:00 │ Manual   │ 4 .  │
├─────────────────────┼──────────┼──────┤
│ 2019-12-12 14:00:00 │ Temporal │ 3 .  │
│ 2019-12-12 14:00:00 │ Manual   │ 3 ─  │
├─────────────────────┼──────────┼──────┤
│ 2019-12-13 00:00:00 │ Temporal │ 4 +  │
│ 2019-12-13 00:00:00 │ Manual   │ 4 +  │
├─────────────────────┼──────────┼──────┤
│ 2019-12-13 01:00:00 │ Temporal │ 3 ─  │
│ 2019-12-13 01:00:00 │ Manual   │ 4 .  │
├─────────────────────┼──────────┼──────┤
│ 2019-12-13 06:00:00 │ Temporal │ 3 .  │
│ 2019-12-13 06:00:00 │ Manual   │ 3 ─  │
├─────────────────────┼──────────┼──────┤
│ 2019-12-13 12:00:00 │ Temporal │ 3 .  │
│ 2019-12-13 12:00:00 │ Manual   │ 4 +  │
├─────────────────────┼──────────┼──────┤
│ 2019-12-14 00:00:00 │ Temporal │ 3 .  │
│ 2019-12-14 00:00:00 │ Manual   │ 5 +  │
├─────────────────────┼──────────┼──────┤
│ 2019-12-14 12:00:00 │ Temporal │ 3 .  │
│ 2019-12-14 12:00:00 │ Manual   │ 6 +  │
├─────────────────────┼──────────┼──────┤
│ 2019-12-14 17:00:00 │ Temporal │ 3 ─  │
│ 2019-12-14 17:00:00 │ Manual   │ 3 ─  │
├─────────────────────┼──────────┼──────┤
│ 2019-12-15 00:00:00 │ Temporal │ 4 +  │
│ 2019-12-15 00:00:00 │ Manual   │ 4 +  │
├─────────────────────┼──────────┼──────┤
│ 2019-12-15 01:00:00 │ Temporal │ 3 ─  │
│ 2019-12-15 01:00:00 │ Manual   │ 3 ─  │
├─────────────────────┼──────────┼──────┤
│ 2019-12-15 12:00:00 │ Temporal │ 4 +  │
│ 2019-12-15 12:00:00 │ Manual   │ 4 +  │
├─────────────────────┼──────────┼──────┤
│ 2019-12-15 13:00:00 │ Temporal │ 3 ─  │
│ 2019-12-15 13:00:00 │ Manual   │ 4 .  │
├─────────────────────┼──────────┼──────┤
│ 2019-12-15 17:00:00 │ Temporal │ 3 .  │
│ 2019-12-15 17:00:00 │ Manual   │ 3 ─  │
├─────────────────────┼──────────┼──────┤
│ 2019-12-16 00:00:00 │ Temporal │ 3 .  │
│ 2019-12-16 00:00:00 │ Manual   │ 4 +  │
├─────────────────────┼──────────┼──────┤
│ 2019-12-16 01:00:00 │ Temporal │ 3 .  │
│ 2019-12-16 01:00:00 │ Manual   │ 3 ─  │
├─────────────────────┼──────────┼──────┤
│ 2019-12-16 12:00:00 │ Temporal │ 4 +  │
│ 2019-12-16 12:00:00 │ Manual   │ 4 +  │
├─────────────────────┼──────────┼──────┤
│ 2019-12-16 13:00:00 │ Temporal │ 3 ─  │
│ 2019-12-16 13:00:00 │ Manual   │ 4 .  │
└─────────────────────┴──────────┴──────┘
```

Comment: I posted a question here about retention being too slow. Sometimes the frequency is longer than daily, maybe weekly. In any case, it's possible to have many remaining records past the retention period if your history table is very large. 
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/306301/retention-not-working-on-temporal-table-or-very-slow

Answer (score 0):

To add to your answer, there is some documentation on MSDN ([How aged rows are deleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/temporal-tables-retention-policy?view=azuresql#how-aged-rows-are-deleted)). The page mentions Azure SQL but it's likely it applies to on-prem, as well.

> The cleanup process depends on the index layout of the history table.
> It is important to notice that only history tables with a clustered
> index (B-tree or columnstore) can have finite retention policy
> configured. A background task is created to perform aged data cleanup
> for all temporal tables with finite retention period. Cleanup logic
> for the rowstore (B-tree) clustered index deletes aged row in smaller
> chunks (up to 10K) minimizing pressure on database log and IO
> subsystem. Although cleanup logic utilizes required B-tree index,
> order of deletions for the rows older than retention period cannot be
> firmly guaranteed. Hence, do not take any dependency on the cleanup
> order in your applications.
>
> The cleanup task for the clustered columnstore removes entire row
> groups at once (typically contain 1 million of rows each), which is
> very efficient, especially when historical data is generated at a high
> pace.